# Sharepoint workflow preventing uploading document properties

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I created a workflow with SharePoint Designer to send a custom email to anyone who uploads a file to the document library (using Created By) reminding checking certain document properties. I set the workflow to be triggered when anyone creates an item in the library.

In the standard Sharepoint document upload sequence, after the user browses and selects the file, then he/she has to assign the relevant properties. When I tested, I've seen that even before I finish typing the properties, I receive the email with no document properties listed, only the file name.

Problem: as I'm completing the metadata/doc properties and click Check In, the form does not close, and does not acknowledge entering the properties. I have to close it with the "X". I refresh the document library view, and no properties have been entered.

I found out that the workflow is preventing the form to send the properties to the library. IF I disable the workflow, everything goes back to normal. I tried Pausing the workflow for 3 minutes just after it is triggered to let me complete the metadata, but it still doesn't work, properties don't get added to the document in the library. The document remains in Checked Out state.

This seems to be a pretty basic problem. I'm a basic SP Designer user. Have you ever had it? Any help will be APPRECIATED !

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that if in SharePoint Designer / Workflow / MyWorkflow / Settings, I toggle off "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name", the problem goes away. I also had to add a first action, to Pause the workflow for some time, to allow the user to complete the metadata when they upload a file (5 min). Does all this ring a bell? Makes sense?